# Como pegar a url para este Json (java android)

Tags: android, json

```
{  
   "success":[  
      {  
         "url":"http:\/\/stream.vagalume.fm\/stream"
      }
   ],
   "format":"mp3",
   "remaining":0
}
```

como fazer para pegar o url, format e remaining separadamente

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar [essa biblioteca](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Ficaria alguma coisa perto disso:

```js
public String getTranslation(String json){  
  JSONObject data = new JSONObject(json);
  return data.getJSONArray("sucesso").getJSONObject(0).getString("url");
}
```